# Making bootable Ubuntu USBstick: fat32 or vfat?

Tags: format, usb-creator

I am trying to make a bootable USB stick, for an Ubuntu workstation,
on an Ubuntu laptop.
All goes well until I actually try to make the bootable stick.
(Startup Disk Creator). Then (soon) it says "input - out put error"
and stops.

The USB stick is vfat. Can that be the problem? Should it be
fat16 or fat32 ?  Is that worth trying, or is it likely to be
something else?  Many Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the ISOs MD5 sum?

Comment: Do you want to install from it, or run it later?

Answer (score 3):

Give it a try! I consider Fat32 the best filesystem for Live USBs.

Install GParted (disk manager) running this command in a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T):

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Insert your USB stick. Backup its content. Open nautilus and **unmount it**.

Then run GParted from a terminal with the command

```
sudo gparted
```

Click the tab GParted > Devices and choose your USB stick.

Right click the USB stick "strip" (probably named /dev/sdb or sdc) and click Format to > Fat32. Apply your actions with that green "V" below the "Device" tab.

Then make the process with Startup Disk Creator again. Things should be fine.